# does every laravel model require a table

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm building a project in laravel 5 and want to create a model that basically converts a day ID (0-6) to a day name (mon-sun). It seems overkill to have a whole table set up for this, when the days are never going to change and an array would do just as well.

If I'm setting up this as a class/model, would I still be required by laravel to have an associated table?

Should I just create a model that doesn't extend the eloquent model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you create a model , needed to input the respective table name, and the operation which you want to perform can define in constant.php or app.php in

```
root_folder/config/app.php  or create file name constant.php in 
root_folder/config/constant.php
```

Comment: are you saying that a model _does_ require a table, but I could define this 'days array' in app.php?

Comment: yes when any page of laravel will load these constant.php will be auto loaded and will be accessible..